# How to create a category/tags page in Jekyll without a list of posts for that tag?

Tags: jekyll

I want to create a Jekyll site where the root page/index.html in root folder just has list of tags/categories (let's say both are the same right now). I want each tag/category to link to a tag_page where it has the tag and the posts associated with each tag. Right now, I have this as my root index.html:

```
{% capture tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    {{ tag[0] }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign sortedtags = tags | split:' ' | sort %}

{% for tag in sortedtags %}
  <h3 id="{{ tag }}">{{ tag }}</h3>
  <ul>
  {% for post in site.tags[tag] %}
    <li><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

which lists the tags and the posts for each tag on the main page.

**Instead,** I would like this:

```
{% capture tags %}
  {% for tag in site.tags %}
    {{ tag[0] }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endcapture %}
{% assign sortedtags = tags | split:' ' | sort %}

{% for tag in sortedtags %}
  <a href="{{ tag.url }}">{{ tag }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

But tag.url doesn't work right now. I would like each tag.url to take me to this following page where it lists the tag name and the posts per tag. How do I do this?

This is my tag_page layout in my _layouts folder. I want this to load when someone clicks on a tag in the index.html file.

```
---
layout: default
---

<h1>{{ page.tag }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for post in site.tags[page.tag] %}
  <li>
    {{ post.date | date: "%B %d, %Y" }}: <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would like to share my implementation of simple tag cloud and tags page. It is working perfectly in this blog [website](http://mnishiguchi.com).

### Demo

- http://mnishiguchi.com/tags

### Implementation

#### 1. Create a partial for a tag cloud

I created a partial `_include/tag_cloud.html` for reusability.
This partial displays all the site tags and each tag links to its corresponding 
section of `tags.html` page. 
It optionally take an array of tag names as an argument.
Using this partial, I can place a list of tags anywhere I wish.

```
{% comment %}
<!--
- If tag_names array is not passed in as argument,
  - Create an empty array,
  - Obtain a tag name and push it to the array, and
  - Sort the tag names.
- List tags as a tag cloud.
-->
{% endcomment %}

{% if include.tag_names %}
  {% assign tag_names = include.tag_names %}

{% else %}
  {% assign tag_names = "" | split: "|"  %}

  {% for posts_by_tag in site.tags %}
    {% assign tag_names = tag_names | push: posts_by_tag.first %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% assign tag_names = tag_names | sort %}
{% endif %}

<ul class="tag-cloud">
  {% for tag_name in tag_names %}
    <li>
      <a href="{{ baseurl }}/tags#{{ tag_name | slugize }}">
        {{ tag_name }}
      </a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

#### 2. Create a page for displaying a tag cloud and post titles under each tag

I create a page `tags.html` that is dedicated to display a tag cloud (created above) and post titles under each tag. At the top of the page, it lists all the tags as a tag cloud, and each tag links to its own section in the page. Below the tag cloud, I place links to blog posts that are grouped by tags.

```
---
layout: page
title: Posts By Tags
permalink: /tags
---

{% assign tag_names = "" | split: "|"  %}

{% for posts_by_tag in site.tags %}
  {% assign tag_names = tag_names | push: posts_by_tag.first %}
{% endfor %}

{% assign tag_names = tag_names | sort %}

{% include tag_cloud.html tag_names=tag_names %}

<hr>

<section class="posts-by-tags">
  {% for tag_name in tag_names %}
    <div>
      <h3 id="{{ tag_name }}">
        {{ tag_name | capitalize | replace: "_", " " }}
      </h3>

      {% for post in site.tags[tag_name] %}
        <a href="{{ post.url | prepend: baseurl }}">
          {{ post.title }}
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

### Related posts

- [Implementing tags in Jekyll site](http://mnishiguchi.com/2016/05/07/implementing-tags-in-jekyll-site/)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, to generate additional `tags/<tag>.html` pages, you will need to [generate pages](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators) with a Jekyll plugin.

The easiest way to implement this would probably just to have a `tags.html` page containing all the posts for all tags, then use JavaScript to show/hide the correct sections. With Jekyll you can still generate urls like `/tags.html#<tag>`, then retrieve the tag name with `window.location.hash`. From there, use JQuery selectors to show/hide the matching elements.